# How to count down remaining time during async.sleep()

Tags: discord.py

First of all, sorry for being a translator.
For the first time, I am making a bot for a personal server using discord.py.
When executing a specific command, the method progresses too fast, so we use asyncio.sleep() to give it some time to proceed slowly.
However, I wanted to show the time of asyncio.sleep() to the user, so I looked for an example, but there is no example that suits me, so I ask a question.
and i'm developing using cog.

ex 1)
5 seconds left.
4 seconds left.
3 seconds left.
.
.
0 seconds left.

ex 2) I'd like to do it this way if possible.

5 seconds left. is displayed
5 seconds left. after deleting
Just 4 seconds left.
Is there any way to become.

```
if not ctx.author.voice.channel == lobby_vc :
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                # asyncio.create_task(self.count_in_server())
                for i in range(len(members)) :
                    await members[i].move_to(lobby_vc)
            else :
                await ctx.send('already gathered')
```

```
     async def count_in_server(self, ctx) :
         for i in range(4,0) :
            await ctx.send(f"{i}s")
```

someone said to create a countdown method using asyncio.create_task, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could do `await asyncio.sleep(1)` and edit the message with seconds left, and put this in a loop (that loops 5 time). But editing the message too frequently is generally not a good idea since it will easily get ratelimited by discord if this command triggers too much in a short time.

Comment: Consider using a built-in relative timestamp to avoid spamming the API & getting ratelimited: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-formats Discord can do all of this for you.